# Spring Boot: Authenticating both a Stateless REST API and a Stateful "Login" Web Controller in the same project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have an application that contains a REST API which is used by a custom java application on an IOT device with no user interaction.And I also have a web app which needs a stateful session for maintaining user login.

Is it possible to use Spring Security to authenticate requests to my API and web controller differently?What form of authentication should I be using for the REST API?

Comment: You want access to same Rest url in **stateful** and **stateless** manner. Or are you talking about having both **stateful** and **stateless** coexist, each for different set of urls?

Comment: If you want to have both stateful and stateless coexist, each for different set of urls, look at my answer below.

Comment: Yes for different urls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to have 2 configurations in your spring security. E.g.

Pay attention to `antMatcher` (**matcher** not matcher**s**). The `antMatcher` will control on what set of url your entire config applies i.e. `FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in below example will apply only to uri matching `/api/test/**`. Of course, you can define the `antMatcher` only in one of the configs say config1 and the other config in that case will be a catch all (i.e catch everything that does not match config1)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {            
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

            http
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {

            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin1").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED); // CONFIGURE TYPE OF SESSION POLICY
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/test/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```